# UML: how to represent indirect operation calls in a sequence diagram?

Tags: uml, class-diagram, operation, sequence-diagram

Consider the following classes:

[image]

I would like to represent in a sequence diagram the fact that an instance of A first navigates through the `b` association end to reach a B instance, then navigates through its association `c` to reach a C instance, then calls the operation `foo()`.

How can I represent this in a sequence diagram? Afaik, navigating from one object to an other is *not* a message, and thus cannot be represented by an arrow, can it? Then how can I show how the C instance is found by the A instance?

My only idea so far is to write `a.b.c` into the name of the C instance lifeline, but I know that this is very likely incorrect:

[image]

---

*EDIT (28/11):* I don't think that this question is a duplicate of [this existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16177894), as here I am interested in representing in a sequence diagram how an object was able to access another object, and not how an object was obtained as a result of a method call / message.

---

*EDIT (28/11 again):* I realized that what the case I have described is wrong, as in fact an *Interaction* (ie. a sequence or communication diagram) has to be contained in a *Classifier*, and can only show *Lifelines* of elements accessible through the properties of the *Classifier*. Thus, with my current class diagram, it is in fact impossible to represent both an instance of A and an instance of C, since there is no candidate *Classifier* referencing both which could be used to contain the sequence diagram.

In other words, afaik, with the proposed class diagram, I cannot have a sequence diagram representing A and C, and I can only represent either A and B, or B and C.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Referencing an instance of a given class in sequence diagrams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16177894/referencing-an-instance-of-a-given-class-in-sequence-diagrams)

Answer (score 2):

In your diagram, you have used the association notation of attributes: `+b` means that `b` is a public attribute of `A` that has is of class `B`, and similarly `c` is a public attribute of `B`.  So the notation `a.b.c:C` could be valid.

However, I'm not 100% sure if this is really valid UML.  The standard foresees an element name and not an expression that determines the element. It allows qualified name, but in a namespace not in a classifier. The optional selector that is possible on the name is also not designed for traversing multiple relationships.

So a better approach would certainly be to give a simple name to your second lifeline (e.g. `x`, or keep it anonymous) and add a **[constraint](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/constraint.html)** that explains how it is determined ( e.g. `{ x = a.b.c }`.  In constraints, be it in OCL, java or natural language, you are allowed to do these kind of access to public attributes.

Now, this might not be desirable from an OO design perspective: using such public members creates a strong coupling and does not offer proper **encapsulation**. I'd therefore use some getter.

The result would then look like:

[image]

Note that if you don't like the assumption for b being known, you can replace the illustrative comment by a real constraint, exactly the way I explained above.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and adding a constraint is indeed interesting! Since an *Interaction* is itself (surprisingly) a *Class* and thus a *Namespace*, it seems it can contain constraints. i wonder whether this is planned by the semantics, but syntactically this appears possible.

Comment: Those are not constraints but notes.

Comment: @ThomasKilian sorry, I didn't put the {contraint} braces

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are not many options. As you see it's nothing you should do anyway since you're violating the paradigm of information hiding.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! My question did not assume that information hiding was considered here, hence I don't see it as a problem. In fact, in some cases such as early domain analysis, some methods advocate using UML without any information hiding, which is how I ended up asking this question.